# What is the most related title to this description?

Tags: sentence-choice

I want to make a video that aims to teach Arabic. I'm gonna teach sentences that are neither formal nor slang. They're casual or normal sentences. Also, those sentences are practical so they don't exist in literature or old books. They are the sentence that people usually use in their conversations with family, friends, or in the street.

What's the most relevant title to the description above:

1. Learn real Egyptian Arabic sentences.
2. Learn the most common Egyptian Arabic sentences.
3. Learn daily life Egyptian Arabic sentences.
4. Learn Egyptian Arabic sentences spoken in the street.
5. Learn daily-life most common Egyptian Arabic sentences.

Which one is the best? Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: "Colloquial" refers to how people speak in everyday conversations.

Comment: Also, FYI, we don't usually *write* the word "gonna".  We just say it that way.  You should write out "going to", except in very informal communication such as texts between friends.

Comment: None of them are "best," it's simply a matter of preference. (I could be wrong, but I believe that, conversationally anyway, *Egyptian Arabic* is simply referred to as *Egyptian*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of adjectives you might use are

> **everyday**
>   Learn *everyday* Egyptian.
>
> **conversational**
>   Learn *informal conversational* Egyptian.